# Animation on changing ImageBitmap of ImageButton

Tags: android, android-animation

Let's say I have an `ImageButton btn`. I have two different `Bitmap`, `bmp1` and `bmp2`. By default, `btn` displays `bmp1`, like this:

```
btn.setImageBitmap(bmp1);
```

Can I somehow make an animation, which crossfades `bmp1` and `bmp2`, when calling the following:

```
btn.setImageBitmap(bmp2);
```

So the question is, is it possible - if yes, how - to animate the changing of bitmaps on ImageButtons?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The way I see it, there are two main ways to implement this functionality.  Note that there may be other methods that will make this happen exactly as you are describing, but these would be my approaches.

### First Approach: Leveraging the `onAnimationEnd()` Callback

Here, you would want to essentially fade out the first `ImageButton`, change the resource in the `onAnimationEnd()` callback, and then fade it back in.  To do this, you would have to implement the below code.

1. Create an `Animation` resource in XML that would be used to fade the `View` in:

   ```
   <!-- Filename: fadein.xml -->
   <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
   <!-- Note that you might want to change the duration here-->
   <alpha 
       android:fromAlpha="0.0" 
       android:toAlpha="1.0"  
       android:duration="250"/> 
   </set>
   ```
2. Create an `Animation` resource in XML that would be used to fade the `View` out:

   ```
   <!-- Filename: fadeout.xml -->
   <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
   <!-- Note that you might want to change the duration here-->
   <alpha 
       android:fromAlpha="1.0" 
       android:toAlpha="0.0"  
       android:duration="250"/> 
   </set>
   ```
3. Load the fade out and fade in `Animation`s in your code:

   ```
   // Obtain a reference to the Activity Context
   Context context = getContext();

   // Create the Animation objects.
   Animation outAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.fadeout);
   Animation inAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.fadein);
   ```
4. Assign a new `AnimationListener` to this `Animation`, and build it out as follows:

   ```
   outAnimation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener(){

       // Other callback methods omitted for clarity.

       public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation){

           // Modify the resource of the ImageButton
           yourImageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.[your_second_image]);

           // Create the new Animation to apply to the ImageButton.
           yourImageButton.startAnimation(inAnimation);                                           
       }
   }
   ```
5. Assign the `Animation` to the `ImageButton`, and start the first `Animation`:

   ```
   yourImageButton.startAnimation(outAnimation);
   ```
6. Then, if you wish to animate back to the previous image, you would simply do the same but in the reverse order.

### Second Approach: Overlay a Second `ImageButton`

For this approach, you would simply assign two `ImageButton`s to the same coordinates on the screen, and with the same width.  Then, you would fade out the first `ImageButton` and fade in the second one after the first `Animation` ended (much like the example above).

---

I hope that this answer aligns with your expectations.  My apologies if there are any code errors, as I am doing this without an editor at the moment.  Please let me know if you would like any additional clarification!

Comment: The first approach looks like exactly what I want to achieve, I will definitely give it a try, thanks!

Comment: It works awesomely, I will have to fine tune a bit of course, but that is my job, thanks once more. :)

Comment: Glad I was able to help!  Good luck on the remainder of your development :).

Comment: Thanks, it is just a little fancy effect in a game, so yea, I have quite much ahead.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to animate image button source changes. The workaround would be to stack two ImageButtons and animate its alfa channel separately to get expected behavior.

Comment: I was thinking about an overlaying view, tho I hoped there was a native solution, guess I will do it this way.